# Are libraries just new sets of commands

Tags: c#, libraries

I am new to programming and I have some questions concerning the libraries.(Please excuse me if some questions seem foolish.)
   - First of all when i searched what libraries are i was told they arereusable code.But when i googled e.g. how to develop a website with C# I found that I need a library.Is this library just a set of commands i can use?Or can it for example allow you to visually create a website?
  -  What's more, in a game designing software I saw it needed C# code for the character movement speed.This means that the software has its own library and needs me to learn new commands?Any additional information would be nice.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: That's a huge question for a Q&A site :) I'd start with some good beginner programming books and work through the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Library contains certain functionality that you want to add to your application. In an extemely simplified example: If you want your application to be able to read and write text files to your computer, you need to import a library tha was written to **help** you read and write files.

You, of course, don't have to use this library, you could write your own. But that would be a waste of time because somebody already created one with easy to use functions like "hey, go get this file" or "hey, write this to a file named FooBar.txt"

Its pre-compiled and **usually** works as expected because thousands other people have used it before you and tested it.

Answer (score 5):

To harken back to the days before computers were in refrigerators, think of each library as a sort of secretary or clerk, with a very specific skill set. So you have:

- a stenographer library
- a typist library
- a out-going-faxes clerk
- a receptionist
- a A/P clerk, etc.

You as the manager of the office (the project), don't want to worry about the details of each task, so you delegate each one to the appropriate clerk or secretary type, and worry only about the higher functions of the business.

Answer (score 3):

A library is more-or-less, just a compiled piece of code; or, a `.dll`.  In order to use it in your project, you would add a reference to the assembly (or `.dll`) and then access it with a `using` statement in your `class` (or where ever you are using it). Something like this:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

There are several options for you to build a website within the .NET stack - like, [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/)/[MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

As to your question about the gaming space, the [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203940.aspx) framework has almost all that you would need to get started making games.